# Android ImageView Two Width

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

Can we apply two widths to ImageView in android?

[image]

I searched a lot online for the solution but 1 or 2 solutions I got is via drawable file. But I don't want to do it with drawable because I want to change ImageView width at runtime from seekbar values. There is two seekbar in my application, one will change the width from top and other will change the width from the bottom on a ImageView.

I tried following too:

```
public class CustomImage extends AppCompatImageView {
    private Path path;

    public CustomImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float h = getMeasuredHeight();
        float w = getMeasuredWidth();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(w * 0.8f, h);
        path.lineTo(w * 0.2f, h);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.close();
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

But it's not working as I want. No drawable solutions please, because it will not work on my app.

Comment: any solution yet?